# Divides later into text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use [materiel ui](https://material-ui.com/components/)

Interested in putting a text followed by a [divider](https://material-ui.com/components/dividers/#divider)

like this

[image]

I tried to do that

```
 <Grid>
    <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
       {'text'}
    </Typography>
    <Divider variant="inset"></Divider>
 </Grid>
```

But this is the result I got

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Please update the question with what you've tried, what you expected, and what you got.  There is not enough information here to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Box`](https://material-ui.com/components/box/) component.

```js
// using display grid
<Box
  display="grid"
  alignItems="center"
  gridColumnGap={16}
  gridTemplateColumns={"1fr auto"}
>
  <Divider />
  <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
    hello world
  </Typography>
</Box>
```

```js
// using flex box
<Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
  <Divider style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginRight: 16 }} />
  <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
    hello world
  </Typography>
</Box>
```

[image: Edit dank-river-08yc2]